# 7ZG.exe - extract subfiles and subdirectories of a specific folder

Tags: 7zip

I have a zipped file with a  **filesFolder**

I want to extract all the content of that directory without the directory root name

the command i tried:

`7zG.exe x "zip.7z" -o"C:\location" "filesFolder\1" "filesFolder\2"`

this gives me the following:

**C:\location\filesFolder\1\***

**C:\location\filesFolder\2\***

what i want is

**C:\location\1\***

**C:\location\2\***

The "e" command is not good since it disables all the inner order of the subfolders

What is the command i need?
Thanks :)

Comment: Probably belongs on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this using just a single 7-zip command and nothing else. However, it should be possible if you use some `move` commands. How about:

```
7zG.exe x "zip.7z" -o"C:\location" "filesFolder\1" "filesFolder\2"
move c:\location\filesfolder\1 c:\location\1
move c:\location\filesfolder\2 c:\location\2
```

If there are no other files to worry about in `c:\location` you could do this using a for loop:

```
for /D %F in (c:\location\filesfolder\*) do move %F c:\location
```

If there are other files in `c:\location` that you don't want to move, and the ones you want to move have sequential suffixes, you could do something like:

```
for /L %N in (1,1,2) do move c:\location\filesfolder\%N  c:\location\%N
```

If you use a for loop in a batch file, replace % with %%.